# How many previous civilizations were there in Desert Punk

Tags: desert-punk

Desert Punk begins by describing a great war that destroyed the previous civilization, and it describes weapons that are recognizable to use as being relics from that war.

The lead character then finds a succession of relics that are greatly in advance of our own, suggesting that the civilization that fought the great war wasn't our civilization, but instead another civilization far into our future, which itself was based on the ruins of an even greater civilization that was destroyed by an even greater war.

This goes on and on, until we get evidence of some kind of robot war, and possible even earlier wars and civilizations.

Is it known exactly how many previous civilizations there were between Desert Punk's civilization and our own?